# What is the sum of internal forces inside a container which has gas in it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, forces, work

Technically form newtons third law sum of internal forces should be zero,but the gas molecules inside the conductor exert some force on the walls of the container,so if the sum of internal forces is zero then how do they exert some force on walls of the container or is my understanding of internal forces wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The container exerts an equal and opposite force on the gas molecules, so the sum of the internal forces is zero. Every time a molecule of gas collides with the wall of the container, the gas molecule exerts a force on the container wall, and the wall exerts a force on the gas molecule. These forces are equal and opposite, as per Newton's 3rd Law. This preserves the sum of the internal forces on the container as zero.

The image below, taken from the Wikipedia article on [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure) illustrates the confusion:
[image: Illustration of gas molecules in a container, with forces from molecule collisions on walls shown as arrows]

The image shows the forces from the gas molecules outwards on the container, but not the forces from the container inwards on the gas molecules. But that's not because they don't exist! I've taken the liberty of modifying the image to show the forces inwards on the gas molecules as blue arrows:
[image]

Now that the forces from the container on the gas molecules are also shown, you can see that the sum of internal forces is indeed zero.

As a side note, in order to consider "internal forces", you have to carefully define what objects are **internal** to the system, and which objects are **external**. Before you start thinking about the sum of internal forces, make sure you're clear about whether you're defining the container walls are internal to (part of) or external to (not part of) the "system" that you're considering. Either way is fine, but you have to be consistent in your definitions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, of course sum of internal forces are zero according to Newton. But the concept is in case of system of particles the sum forces the particle exert on one another are cancelled but gas molecules inside the vessel can't be system of particle. They are independent individual particle that are moving in some crazy zig zag path.  these two are different things.